# Migrating QuincyKit server from 2 to 3

Tags: quincykit

The readme at the QuincyKit site suggests setting up a brand new server instance. Still, has anyone tried migrating QuincyKit v2 server to v3? The schema doesn't look all that different...

I'm only using QK for iOS crashes, no MacOS.

Specifically, I'm wondering if:

- legacy app builds can send their crashes to a v3 URL
- vice versa - v3 client can send to a v2 server
- v3 symbolication will work for those
- crashes from v2 database can be imported into a v3 one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

The database schema is almost identical. Only one table (`crash_groups`) doesn't allow for easy automatic migration; fields `pattern`, `reason`, `exception` and `location` need to be repopulated in PHP from existing crash reports, parsed anew with Quincy 3. I could share the code if there's interest.

One more table has a deleted field (`crash.username` is gone), but it was blank in my case anyway.

The rest of the tables translate field-for-field.

Some of the crashes, for some reason, didn't have a crash group (groupid=0); probably database hiccups.

The crash submission interface is perfectly backwards compatible; if you copy crash_v300.php to crash_v200.php, legacy app versions can submit their crashes with no trouble.